# Loop counting files twice in php

Tags: php

I have the following function that searches through a folder, grabs all files  and folders not beginning with a "."

```
$results = [];
function getDirCount($directory, &$results, $friend, $static_path) {
    $i = 0;      
    $entries = scandir($directory);
    foreach ($entries as $item) {
        if (!in_array($item, ['.', '..']) && substr($item, 0, 1) !== '.') {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $item;
            $rel_path = $static_path . '/' . $item;
            if (is_dir($path)) {
                getDirCount($path, $results, $friend, $rel_path);
            } else {
                $i++;
                $pathInfo = pathinfo($path);
                $name = $pathInfo['filename'];
                $type = 'unknown';
                if (!empty($pathInfo['extension'])) {
                    $name .= "." . $pathInfo['extension'];
                    switch (strtolower($pathInfo['extension'])) {
                        case "gif":
                        case "jpg":
                        case "png":
                        case "jpeg":
                        case "bmp":
                        //etc..
                        $type = 'image';
                        break;
                        case "mp4":
                        $type = 'video';
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $tttt = filemtime($path);
                $data = [
                    'name' => $name,
                    'username' => $friend,
                    'path' => $rel_path,
                    'type' => $type,
                    'id' => $i,
                    'time' => date('F d Y h:i A', $tttt)
                ];
                $results[] = $data;
            }
        } 
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Then I have created a loop, to count all the files.

```
$friend = strtolower($row['username']);
$directoryToScan = '/absolute/path/to/files/'.$friend;
$rel_path = '/relative/path/to/files/'.$friend;
$tree = getDirCount($directoryToScan, $data, $friend, $rel_path);
for($i=(count($data)-1)-($feed-1);$i>=(count($data)-10)-($feed-1);$i--){
    $c = 0;
    if ($data !== NULL) {
        if(($data[$i]['type']=='image') && ($data[$i]['username'] == $friend)) {
            $c++;
      }
      $photo_count=$c;
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is, every file is being counted twice and output twice. So if I drop a file in a users directory and check, the count will increase by two. If I drop 5 files, the count is increasing by 10.

I have also tried to move the $c = 0 to before the for statement, but then it seems to indefinitely return 1 even when there are dozens of results. Obviously I am looking to get a correct file count.

**UPDATE**

Adding more code to help explain what $feed is.

On one page I have the following ajax request.

```
<script>
    var feed;
    function loadmorefeed() {
        if (feed === undefined || feed === null || feed == '') { feed = 0; }
        feed = feed + 1;
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'stream_feed.php',
            'type': 'get',
            'data': {
                'feed': feed
            },
            'success': function (data) {
                $('.get_stream').append(data);
                return;
            },
            'error': function (request, status, error) {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
    loadmorefeed(); loadmorefeed(); loadmorefeed();
</script>
```

And then on the page doing the counting I have

```
$feed=$_GET['feed'];
```

Comment: Maybe for loop conditions are wrong? You may need to do 2 loops and set $c=0; between both (after begin the second)

Comment: As you do not enlighten us as to what `$feed` may contain I am gona move on to a sensible question

Comment: @RiggsFolly I didn't really see it as important to the question. $feed contain $feed = $_GET[feed]. $_GET[feed] is a never ending incriment starting from feed + 1 and then fed via a GET request using ajax.

Comment: and now I updated the coded. Though it doesn't change how sensible the question is.

Comment: @Bruce why do you execute `loadmorefeed();` 3 times? am not really good with ajax and js but isnt that will run `'stream_feed.php'` 3 times?

Comment: You think you have a problem with a loop. The loop is a bit complex and uses a variable called `$feed` to control its iterations ___and you dont see that it contents and makeup might be pertinent to a solution!___ Maybe thats why you are having problems

Comment: @Xyuri, the effect is similar to a facebook stream or a twitter stream. So on first load, it loads three results, then as one reaches the bottom of the page, it runs the functions, over and over and over.

Comment: @RiggsFolly "and you dont see that it contents and makeup might be pertinent to a solution!" You are correct I don't see them as pertinent to the solution. And if this is why I am having issues, I would love for someone to show me where, as the code is now displayed above.

Comment: aha well, why dont you merge that `$c++` with the `if (!empty($pathInfo['extension']))` to make it something like this `if($type=='image'){$c++}` inside the function itself?

Comment: using `$GLOBALS` maybe, so you will be counting the files the moment you get them

Comment: the above `if($type=='image'){$c++}` is missing a `;` after `$c++` should be `if($type=='image'){$c++;}`

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on the $feed and why you want it to be to count the files.
To Count all the files you can use the below after function

```
//GIVES YOU THE TOTAL COUNT
$TotaFilesScaned = count($data);


//TO GET THE COUNT OF IMAGES ONLY  
$photo_count = 0;
for($i=0; $i<$TotaFilesScaned;$i++){
    if(isset($data[$i]) && ($data[$i]['type']=='image') && ($data[$i]['username'] == $friend)) 
    {
            $photo_count++;
    }
}
echo $photo_count;
```